# Video Indexer Render Project API not working

Tags: api, azure-video-indexer

I am trying to render a project I created using the Video Indexer "Create Project" API call, but I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "ErrorType": "USER_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "Message": "Token is authorized to access only a video. Trace id: '6a0bd50f-d25e-405f-b853-86847c8a1bca"
}
```

I'm following the following steps from the API documentation:

1. Create a project:

[https://api.videoindexer.ai/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Projects[?accessToken]](https://api.videoindexer.ai/%7Blocation%7D/Accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/Projects%5B?accessToken%5D)

This returns the new project information and 200 Ok status code.

2. Get the project access token by sending a GET request to:

[https://api.videoindexer.ai/Auth/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Projects/{projectId}/AccessToken[?allowEdit]](https://api.videoindexer.ai/Auth/%7Blocation%7D/Accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/Projects/%7BprojectId%7D/AccessToken%5B?allowEdit%5D)

An access token is returned successfully.

3. Send a POST request to render the video:
   [https://api.videoindexer.ai/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Projects/{projectId}/render[?sendCompletionEmail][&accessToken]](https://api.videoindexer.ai/%7Blocation%7D/Accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/Projects/%7BprojectId%7D/render%5B?sendCompletionEmail%5D%5B&accessToken%5D)

** for the access token parameter, I am passing in the project access key in all cases

However, the documentation for this API doesn't specify the schema for the body of the call, so when I send an empty body, it returns the error:

```
{
"ErrorType": "USER_NOT_ALLOWED",
"Message": "Token is authorized to access only a video. Trace id: '6a0bd50f-d25e-405f-b853-86847c8a1bca"
```

}

I have also tried a different approach of calling the Project widget and using the "Render" button that the widget provides, but I can neither save nor render the videos that show up in the project.

My end goal is to be able to edit the videos and render the selected video ranges.
Any advice regarding this issue is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering a project is an operation that requires access to other videos in your Video Indexer account (the videos that are included in the project).

Therefore, make sure you use an account access token (obtained with allowEdit=true) for step 3, or just use the same token you used to create the project from step 1.